# BAT commands to recognize if process is running and display prompt

Tags: batch-file, process, command-prompt, prompt

I need to create a bat that recognizes if a process is running, and if the process is running I need to add a prompt asking if the user wants to end the process to continue with some other tasks. 
I have the command to recognize if a process is running(this is the one that worked for me):

```
@echo off
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq vmware-view.exe" | find /i "vmware-view.exe" >nul && (
echo VMWare Horizon is running
) || (
echo VMWare Horizon is not running
)
pause>nul
```

and I have the command to prompt for an imput:

```
@echo off
setlocal
:PROMPT
SET /P AREYOUSURE=Are you sure (Y/[N])?
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" NEQ "Y" GOTO END
```

But I don't know how to put those 2 together to say that, if the process is running, display prompt asking user if bat can end process to continue with an update, and if not running just go on with update.

could you please assist?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I remember from the old DOS days that you could use GOTOs.

for instance a bat file containing the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO something
GOTO LABEL0

ECHO something else
GOTO LABEL1

:LABEL0
ECHO some label

:LABEL1
ECHO some other label
```

will print:

```
something
some label
some othe label
```

you will not see

```
something else
```

because the first GOTO skipped to LABEL0

You can use a label like :QUIT or :END at the end of your bat and skip at the end if you have nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use ERRORLEVEL to see if TASKLIST and FIND got the process. Afterwards use CHOICE.

```
@echo off
set task=vmware-view.exe

tasklist | find /i "%task%" > nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo task is running.
    choice /c yn /t 10 /d n /m "should we kill it?"
    if errorlevel 2 goto end
    taskkill /f /im "%task%"
) else (
    echo task is not running.
)

:update
echo updating...

:end
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for. :)